# splitting a comma-separated string with or without double quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have these line of strings:

```
#input:
"A & B/C,1,2"
"\"D, E & F\",1,2"
```

which I would like to convert into arrays.

```
#output:
["A & B/C",1,2]
["D, E & F",1,2]
```

`split(",")` is not suitable for this, so I tried regex:

```
str.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)")
str.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)")
```

both of these produces extra quote on the output:

```
["A & B/C,1,2"]
["\"D, E & F\",1,2"]
```

Can you please point out the wrong in the regex?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933065/how-do-i-split-apart-a-csv-string-in-ruby

Answer (score 0):

How about the code using scan like this ?

```
str.scan(/((?:(?:\"[^"]*\")|[^,])*),?/)[0...-1].map(&:first)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you are looking for

```
(?:^|,)(?=[^"]|(")?)"?((?(1)[^"]*|[^,"]*))"?(?=,|$)
```

From: [Regex to split a CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144431/regex-to-split-a-csv)